# JQuery - Adding More Than 1 Attachment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a button called "Add New Attachment" and 5 attachment field sets. Every time I click on this button, one attachment field set appears and if I click on this button again, one more attachment field set appears, so on and so forth.

My code right now appears 5 attachment field sets at once when the button is clicked!  How can I get this action works?  Please give a hand. [Live Code](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/qkjfkyd3/)
Thank you so much!

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="AddButtn">Add New Attach</button>
<p>
<div id="mainAttach" class="uploadCover">
    <input id="attach1">Attach 1</input><br />
    <input id="attach2">Attach 2</input><br />
    <input id="attach3">Attach 3</input><br />
    <input id="attach4">Attach 4</input><br />
    <input id="attach5">Attach 5</input>
</div>
</p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#AddButtn').click(
            function()
            {
                $('#mainAttach').removeClass('uploadCover');
            }
        );
    });
```

CSS

```
.uploadCover{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the input and then increment the index like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').hide();
    var index = 0;
    $('#AddButtn').click(function () {
        index += 1;
        $('#mainAttach').removeClass('uploadCover');
        $('#attach' + index).show();
    });
});
```

**[Working demo click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ej3xq6mg/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow, there are many ways to achieve this task.

Comment: @abcidd All good, `:)` glad it helped, you just need to play around and fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle take off the display none

http://jsfiddle.net/8r1ahf9k/

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var count = 5;
        $('#AddButtn').click(
            function()
            {
                count++;
                if (count > 10) {
                  alert('Sorry too many attachments');
                  return;
                }
                $('#mainAttach').append('<input id="attach' + count + '">Attach ' + count + '<br />');
            }
        );
    });
```